# Populating a UITableView with data from a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

what I am simply trying to do is populate my table view with data from a preexisting [String:String] dictionary. I have found countless examples and tutorials on how to do this with an array, but none on how to do it with a dictionary. It does not matter to me in what order the dictionary values get put in the tableview.

I have a separate UITableViewCell class that has outlets to my cell, and I just need to find out how to link this dictionary to the table view. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need an array because the rows of a table view are ordered.

Comment: Even if the order is completely irrelevant in my case for the tableview?

Comment: you can use Array(dict.values) as the tableview datasource.

Comment: @willcohen Yes because you populate rows based on an index path (section and row). As the user scrolls, the data needs to be stable.

Comment: @maddy oops sorry I always thought dict.values is lazymapcollection or something which cannot be subscript. my bad.

Comment: @koropok Actually, you were right. I was thinking of `NSDictionary allValues`, not Swift `Dictionary.values`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can never guarantee that your dictionary contents will come out in the same order it went in, you cannot do it directly from a dictionary.  Therefore you would need to do it indirectly using a separate array that is based on the dictionary keys (for example).

One such way of doing this would be to create an array based on the sorted keys of the dictionary thusly:

```
sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(<)
```

Then in your UITableView delegate/data-source methods use `indexPath.row` as index to the `sortedKeys` array to grab a key the array.  Then use that key, to grab the value from your dictionary.

Comment: Is that true even when it does not mater to me what order it goes into the tabelview?

Comment: Absolutely true.  The order may not matter to you, but there must be a defined order for the table view to use.  By definition, a table view gets its cell data by indexes (integers), which must therefore be used in an ordered list of some sort.  An array is the logical data structure to use for this.