# How to update keys and values at particular index in dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

Getting details of source index and and removing those values by storing it

but how to add the stored data at destination or at destination index???

Am using dictionaries keys and values to display data in the customized cell/row

Here am trying to move the cells in table view, from source to destination.

Getting details of source index and and removing is working fine but how to add the same data at destination or at destination index???

Here is my code:

```
let indexSource = dic1.index(forKey: (Array(dic1.keys)[sourceIndexPath.row]))

let rearrangedDataDic = dic1[indexSource!]

dic1.remove(at: indexSource!)

let indexDest = dic1.index(forKey: (Array(dic1.keys)[destinationIndexPath.row]))

dic1.updateValue(rearrangedDataDic.value, forKey: rearrangedDataDic.key)
```

Comment: Dictionaries are *unordered* collections and not suitable as a table view data source. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093515/populating-a-uitableview-with-data-from-a-dictionary

Comment: Use an array that contains the keys of the dictionary as a bridge between the table view and the dictionary, that is this array becomes the data source for the table view but instead if using the array elements directly in the table view you fetch the data to be displayed from the dictionary